# How does the pytest increment example code work to skip tests (pytest item and call objects?)

Tags: python, pytest, increment

I am trying to figure out how the example code in the pytest docs using the increment marker to skip tests works, found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html) under "incremental testing - test steps".

I'm trying to understand how it works as I want to modify it to run with slightly different behaviour.

My end goal would be to modify the code so that if I had a class with 6 functions, for example do something likeskip function 2 and 3 if 1 fails and skip 5 and 6 if 4 fails, but not if 1 fails.

The code at the bottom in full is from the example lets you add a pytest marker `@pytest.mark.incremental` for a test function or class. If a function in the class marked with an incremental marker fails, all further functions in the class will get skipped.

As I understand the code in the conftest.py file gets called every time a test function runs. I think `pytest_runtest_makereport` runs after a test is finished, and somehow using 'excinfo' finds out if the test passed or not.

I don't really how the following lines work:

```
  parent = item.parent
  parent._previousfailed = item
```

What is `item` and `item.parent`? Why is the `parent._previousfailed` attribute being set to `item`?

`pytest_runtest_setup` Checks to see if `item.parent` has this `_previousfailed` attribute and if so fails the test.

I'm confused as to what the item and call arguments being passed are. I found the following [reference guide](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#item) which makes mention of the item type, but doesn't really clarify much.

Also why do the `pytest_runtest_makereport` and `pytest_runtest_setup` functions get called. Are they special 'keyword' function names within the pytest framework?

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest


def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    if "incremental" in item.keywords:
        if call.excinfo is not None:
            parent = item.parent
            parent._previousfailed = item


def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    if "incremental" in item.keywords:
        previousfailed = getattr(item.parent, "_previousfailed", None)
        if previousfailed is not None:
            pytest.xfail("previous test failed (%s)" % previousfailed.name)



# content of test_step.py

import pytest


@pytest.mark.incremental
class TestUserHandling(object):
    def test_login(self):
        pass

    def test_modification(self):
        assert 0

    def test_deletion(self):
        pass


def test_normal():
    pass
```